# Append li after succes function in jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $('#eventForm').submit(function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          var fd = new FormData(this);
          var msg =document.getElementById('msg').value;
                    var data = {};
                    data.message = msg;

          $.ajax({
               url: '/messages/<%= id %>',
               data: data,
               dataType: "JSON",
               type: 'POST',
               success: function(data){

               alert();
                     $("ul").append('<li class="message left appeared">hgdfhgjdhfjghdfj</li>');




                  //  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
               }

          });
     });
            </script>
```

And the posting data here in controller. Its succesfully posting and insert the data but li is not append. And in the console there is no error.

```
 BASE.APP.post('/messages/:id',BASE.urlEncodedParser, function(req,res)
     {


            var body = req.body;

        var msgdata ={
        "contactID" : req.params.id,
        "message" : body.message,
        "token" : req.usersession.token

        }

    var digest = BASE.utils.hmac("sha1", "A12AA418-1F28-4464-8B67-29CBD02BC45C-F048B14F-F3E3-4F97-A522-F2275A364A0E", JSON.stringify(msgdata));

    var sendData = {

    "contactID" : req.params.id,
    "token" :req.usersession.token,
    "message":body.message,
    "digest"    : digest

    };
    //console.log(sendData);

    var textPostdata = BASE.utils.base64encode(BASE.utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(sendData)));
//  console.log(textPostdata);
    BASE.request({
                url : "http://example.com/sendTextMessage/",
                method :"POST",
                headers : {

                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
                    body : textPostdata
                },
            function (err,result,body) {
                    //console.log(typeof body);
                    var textbody = JSON.parse(body);
                   res.send('controller success');
 });


});
```

> I want to append
>
> here  
>   but its shows nothing while i used to alert its not come in success
>   part of jquery

Comment: do you have any error in console ? Is the success triggering?

Comment: no i am not getting any errors. Success is not triggering if i am writing alert   success: function(data){
    
               alert('ok');
      $("ul").append('<li class="message left appeared">hgdfhgjdhfjghdfj</li>');
      
      
    
       
      //  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
               } its shows nothing

Comment: you have the "controller success" message ? do you see the ajax call in devTools ? Is it responding 200 ?

Comment: yes its give me controller success messgae and its respond 200

Comment: please try a `console.log(arguments, $('ul'))` into the success callback

Comment: It is not triggering the `success` callback, because it's deprecated, try changing `success` with `done`, see here for reference [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: by the way, you should specify which version of jquery you're using

Comment: Jquery v1.11.1.........nd am using done instead of success its show nothing

Comment: ok so, you see the ajax call starting, it responds with 200 and with a payload but the success/done callback is not triggering :O am i right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109679/discussion-between-pietro-lerro-and-sumit-aggarwal).